# Daily change each page on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I put one app on google app engine.

My app has one cronjob which is parse data from Internet and store into my db.

When user using my app, it will extract data from db, and show data to users.

I found that is too time consuming and too many request from db.

I want to revise each page when the cronjob running daily.

Then user can see the page without query my database.

How can I do that in GAE ?

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Not nearly enough info in the question to help you.  For example, what does "too many request from db" mean?  Is it because you have a lot of traffic?  Or you are querying the db too much?
Possible solutions are:

1. Edge cache your page: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/6xAV2Q5x8AU/discussion
2. Store your page in memcache.
3. Optimize your database accesses.  Most likely you're doing something very inefficiently.
4. Use a cronjob to generate your page, store it in the blobstore, and redirect your fetches to the blobstore.  You can do this, but this is a pretty dumb way to go about it, given that there are better options.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid it's a limitation of GAE, according to [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/ImkolUIYJcs), no matter how much caching and tricky solutions you find. They just worsen google's policies.

You can't have what you need if you don't write directly inside the html file and store it on the server every time, which is far more resource consuming and, in my opinion, just pointless. Since GAE is a free service, with the purpose of testing, you should acquaint with what you have, or pay.